# Android ListView setVisibility not working

Tags: android, listview, user-interface

I have a ListView in my RelativeLayout that is supposed to be hidden during a search is executed. Therefore I implemented the following code:

```
mProgressView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
mSearchListView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
mSearchAdapter.search(query).onSuccess(new Continuation<Set<Integer>, Object>() {
    @Override
    public Object then(final Task<Set<Integer>> task) throws Exception {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() 
                mSearchAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                mProgressView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                mSearchListView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });
        return null;
    }
});
```

Unfortunately, the ListView stays visible. The ProgressView start to spin successfully but the list view remains visible. Any hints on what to do?

Comment: Sometimes behavior could occur when the UI is not being updated from within the UI thread.  This doesn't always produce errors, but on occasion just doesn't do what the caller is requesting of it.  So, I would check to see if you are doing these changes on a UI thread (which should be the case for updates such as these).

Comment: I actually did. And I suppose the progress view wouldn't also work properly, when not updated from the UI thread

Answer (score 0):

When you say it stays 'visible' do you mean you see data in the listview or just that some space seems to be occupied by an invisible listview?

If the latter is the case then you should try making the listview GONE as -

```
mSearchListView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

instead of making it invisible

Comment: I still see the content. I also already tried using GONE, no change at all :(

Comment: mSearchListView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

Comment: Are you sure you are looking for the correct listview? meaning the id by which you look it up is correct? Can you post a more detailed code, it will be easier to figure out what's going on that way.